# How do I pick up important but correlated variables as they mask each other's removal?

Tags: correlation, importance

Most variable importance methods work by randomly permuting the values in each variable taken one at a time and then measuring the change in the evaluation metric (e.g. increase in RMSE for regression). I assume then that two highly correlated but important variables, when permuted together, can cause a large increase in RMSE, but removing each individually may only cause a small increase in RMSE. So, while measuring importance, one of these variables is masking the importance of the other as they provide similar information content with regard to the prediction.

The first solution I can think of is to do the permutations with pairs of variables. The problem with this is that there may be more than two important but correlated variables. Doing this with more than pairs (and sometimes even pairs) becomes computationally infeasible. Are there any other ways to pick up the importance of these correlated variables?

Comment: One thing one can do is bag the variables a la RF.  This is what I would call standard variable importance.  This would certainly give one (at least)  hints.  Secondly, I'm curious as to the why ?  If the two variables are highly correlated 'either' should provide similar results.

Comment: Take the extreme case where the two are perfectly correlated (cor=1), then removing either should lead to no performance degradation. I'm not sure I understand your first three sentences. Or your last sentence for that matter, I just had a guess at the meaning.